# Search nodes with paragraph

Tags: 8, search, paragraphs

I have the following query:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
            ->condition('type', 'case_study')
            ->condition('status', '1')
            ->sort('changed', 'DESC')
            ->pager(4);


$query->condition('title', "%QUERY%", "LIKE");


$nids = $query->execute();
```

This works fine, however it obviously only searches on the title of the node. My case study nodes' fields are structured like this

```
- Case Study
    - title
    - field_page_banner
    - ...
    - field_rows <-- this is my paragraphs field
```

The paragraphs can contain multiple types and are chosen by the user when creating the content.

I want to be able to alter my query so that it searches the content of the paragraphs. For example, if the user adds a 'Rich Text' paragraph type, it will search the text.

This works fine for the built in search functionality, I just want to create a page of case studies with search functionality.

I am using Drupal 8.2.4 and Paragraphs 8.x-1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The \Drupal::entityQuery object doesnt support JOINs I believe:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/interface/QueryInterface/8.2.x

If it did you could Join onto the Paragraph bundle and LIKE across that all you want.

I recommend the following approach with Views, a small chance exists it may not work:

- Create a View of your case study Nodes
- add a relationship to the Paragraph bundle (if needed)
- assure the field list for the View includes `title` and `field_rows` (you can Exclude field_rows from showing in your view if you want).
- add a `Grouped Filter` and `Expose` it and select it to use your `title` and `field_rows` values.

That should do the trick...

Comment: This sounds like it might be exactly what I want, however I'm stuck at the `Grouped Filter`, is this the same thing as the normal `Filter Criteria` or `Contextual Filters` options? Or is this something different?

Comment: A `Group Filter` is an option when adding a `Filter Criteria`. You must have already added the fields you want to group upon to your View.

Comment: Ah I see, I'm not getting a `Group Filter` option, could it have been renamed to `Combine fields filter`? Or am I missing a module?

Answer (score 1):

After keep on testing and write the query i found out it do support join for paragraph. Below is my query

`$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('field_content_type_paragraph_name.entity.field_paragraph_field_machine_name.target_id',"NODE ID HERE");
$entity_ids = $query->execute();`

Here is the generated query

```
[node__field_content_type_paragraph_name] => Array
                    (
                        [join type] => INNER
                        [table] => node__field_content_type_paragraph_name
                        [alias] => node__field_content_type_paragraph_name
                        [condition] => node__field_content_type_paragraph_name.entity_id = base_table.nid
                        [arguments] => Array
                            (
                            )
                    )

                [paragraphs_item] => Array
                    (
                        [join type] => LEFT OUTER
                        [table] => paragraphs_item
                        [alias] => paragraphs_item
                        [condition] => paragraphs_item.id = node__field_content_type_paragraph_name.field_content_type_paragraph_name_target_id
                        [arguments] => Array
                            (
                            )
                    )

                [paragraph__field_paragraph_field_machine_name] => Array
                    (
                        [join type] => INNER
                        [table] => paragraph__field_paragraph_field_machine_name
                        [alias] => paragraph__field_paragraph_field_machine_name
                        [condition] => paragraph__field_paragraph_field_machine_name.entity_id = paragraphs_item.id
                        [arguments] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )
```